# How to store the output of the Invoke-RestMethod into a variable

Tags: powershell

I am trying to store the output of the `Invoke-RestMethod` into a variable and than exact the output from the variable.

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $exportURL -Headers $logonHeader -ContentType "application/zip" -TimeoutSec 2700 -OutFile "$PlatformZipPath\$PlatformID.zip" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$URI = New-Object System.Uri("$URL_DeployPlatfoms/$Repository/$Valut/$EMV/$platfromTech/$PlatformID.zip")  
    
$AF_PWD = ConvertTo-SecureString $JfrogAuthToken -AsPlainText -Force  
$AFCREDS = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($Jfroguser, $AF_PWD)  

$SOURCE = "$PlatformZipPath\$PlatformID.zip"  
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URI -InFile $SOURCE -Method Put -Credential $AFCREDS
```

So, What this piece of code of does is export the cyberark platform and deploy to jfrog artifactory. But the invoke rest method store platform zip locally. I dont want. I want to directly deploy it to artifactory.
But i dont know how to do that. Please help me with that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$request = Invoke-WebRequest ...` Then look at `$request.Content`